# How i can have two effects for my data-dismiss="modal" ;one to reload the parent page , while the other without loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application. and i define the following javascript to always reload the parent page when the user close the modal dialog:-

```
  $(function () {

        $(document).on('click', 'button[data-dismiss]', function (e) {
            location.reload();
        }); });
```

but i need to make this more dynamic, basically by having the option to specify if i want to reload the parent page or not. so i moved the modal header to be inside a partial view as follow, and pass a bool value to reload or not:-

```
@model Boolean

<div class="modal-header">


     @{if(Model){ //Reload
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>}
    else if(!Model){ //Do not reload
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal2" aria-hidden="true">×</button>}
        }

    </div>
```

so i will be calling the modal header as follow:-

```
 Html.RenderPartial("_modalHeader",true);
```

The problem i am facing is as follow:-

how to specify if i want to reload the parent record or not, inside the :-

```
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
```

Second problem how to let javascript know weather to reload or not?

Comment: modals are the worst... just fyi

Comment: I don't understand your first question, as to your second you just check a property in your event handler. is the `modal` and `modal2` what decides whether to reload or just the naming?

Comment: @Arian could u explain what do u mean?

Comment: @user1950929 now in both cases i will have a data-dismiss="modal" ,, but one that will force the "location.reload();" while the other will not , based on the Bool value i pass to the partial view..

Comment: you can just add a class like `force-reload` or even your own property `data-force-reload` to the button and check it in the handler

Comment: @johnG [See here](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12637/what-research-is-there-suggesting-modal-dialogs-are-disruptive) Bottom line: Modal dialogs can double error rates, increase time to task completion, and are near-universally despised by users. Alternate means of notification are often available and should be utilized wherever possible and appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, if I understand your question correctly:

```
@model Boolean

<div class="modal-header">


     @{if(Model){ //Reload
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" data-reload="yes" aria-hidden="true">×</button>}
    else if(!Model){ //Do not reload
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" data-reload="no" aria-hidden="true">×</button>}
        }

    </div>
```

and in your JS:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'button[data-dismiss]', function (e) {
        if($(this).attr('data-reload') == 'yes')
            location.reload();
        else
            $(this).parents('.modal').first().modal('hide');
    }); 
});
```

Comment: i mean what i should add inside the else  ?

Comment: i tried this " else {
                $(this).hide();
            }" . but this will hide the close button and not the modal popup..

Comment: you have to call `.modal("hide")` on the modal itself

Comment: I edited my answer, it searches for the first ancestor with the `modal` class (which the modal should have) and then calls the modal close on it. please tell me if it works.

Comment: $(this).parents('.modal').first().modal('hide'); worked well , also .modal("hide") worked